# How to distort a Sprite into a trapezoid?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to transform a Sprite into a trapezoid, I don't really care about the interpolation even though I know without it my image will lose detail. All I really want to do is Transform my rectangular Sprite into a trapezoid like this:

---

```
  /      \  
 /        \ 
/__________\
```

Has anyone done this with CGAffineTransforms or with cocos2d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation you're proposing is not affine.  [Affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) have to be undoable.  So they can typically:

- Scale
- Rotate
- Shear (make lopsided, like square -> parallelogram)
- Translate

But they cannot "squeeze".  Notice that the left and right sides of your trapezoid, if extended, would intersect at a particular spot.  They're not parallel anymore.  So you couldn't "undo" the transformation, because if there was anything to transform at that spot, you couldn't decide where they would transform to.  In other words, if a transformation doesn't preserve parallelism, it pinches space, can't be undone, and isn't affine.

I don't know that much about transformations in Core Animation, so I hope that mathy stuff helps you find an alternative.

But I do know how you could do it in OpenGL, but it would require you to start over on how you draw your application:

1. If I'm envisioning the result you want correctly, you want to build your rectangle in 3D, use an affine transformation to rotate it away a little bit, and use a (non-affine) projection transformation to flatten it into a 2D image.
2. If you're not looking for a 3D effect, but you really just want to pinch in the corners, then you can specify a `GL_RECT` with the points of your trapezoid and map your sprite onto it as a texture.

The easiest thing might be to pre-squeeze your image in a photo editor, save it as a .png with transparency, and draw a rectangle with that image.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you so much for your input. Both of your options are great, however I forgot to mention that I want my Sprite to be initially a regular rectangular Shape and then dynamically transform it into a trapezoid. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: That is possible using the OpenGL methods I described.  I guess the one about saving it in a photo editor is off the table.

Comment: can you sheer in a NSAffineTransform? I dont think you can, if you could you could keystone...

Comment: i dont really think that being reversible is a requirement per se, just a byproduct that there would be an inverse matrix most transforms... those that dont require dividing by zero to solve the inverse

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes you can shear in an affine transform. I don't think there are helper functions to create such a matrix, but you can do it. Start with the identity matrix, then alter m12 or m21 to shear X by Y or Y by X.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a CATransform3D to the layer of the UIView.
To find out the right one, it is easier to use [AGGeometryKit](https://github.com/hfossli/AGGeometryKit/).

```
#import <AGGeometryKit/AGGeometryKit.h>

UIView *view = ...; // create a view

view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
AGKQuad quad = view.layer.quadrilateral;
quad.tl.x += 20; // shift top left x-value with 20 pixels
quad.tr.x -= 20; // shift top right x-value with 20 pixels
view.layer.quadrilateral = quad; // the quad is converted to CATransform3D and applied
```